# How to create computed properties with Typescript in Vuejs

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I keep getting this error in browser `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "dataElements"`

I have `@Prop() private dataElements: any[];` in my component. This prop is changed by the parent and by the child, also it might need a watcher to do some operations when it is changed.

How can i create a computed property out of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid mutating a prop directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752919/avoid-mutating-a-prop-directly)

Comment: @Rich kinda is and kinda isnt. Im using Typescript so  i cant use the solution offered there. I need a solution in Typescript not in Javascript. I-d do the conversion myself, but i dont know Vue well enoguh for it.

Answer (score 0):

As of for Vue you should never have to mutate a `prop` (which has been passed to a child component through the parent), because whatever you do within the child component - the parent can always change and overwrite the `prop`s value (as already stated in the error message).

To mutate a passed in `prop` you have to define a locally used one in your child component. In your case this can be done by a `computed` property which just returns a newly created array depending on your `prop`.

```
computed: {
    elements() {
        return [...this.dataElements]
    }
}
```

Any change on the array should always be reported to the parent, by emitting an event, which at the end will handle the appropriate mutation and pass the `prop` back again to the child.

Comment: Im not actually modifying the props. I only have a initilizer for it in constructor. Other than that i just read the prop. This error is so annoying. I either get error that it is not initilized or i get error that im mutating it. There is no pleasing the compiler.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your exact line of code? While initializing something in the constructor - Do you mutate the prop? Even that shouldn't be done, due to Vues reactivity system.

Comment: constructor() {
        super();
       this.dataElements = [];
    }